# Teamcity Multi Value Configuration Variables

Tags: teamcity, cicd

I want to utilize ConfParameters in Teamcity in a way that its value can be dynamic based on the environment specific value user selects.
Is this possible. I searched a lot, but I guess isn't supported.
Any help will be appreciated.

example:

```
if %env.val%="qa":
   dbuser="qauser" 
else if %env.val%="stage":
   dbuser="stageuser"
```

.. and so on some logic

And I want this dbuser as a Conf parameter in Teamcity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could take this solution:

```
if %env.val%="qa":
   dbuser="qauser"
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.dbuser' value='qauser']"
else if %env.val%="stage":
   echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.dbuser' value='stage']"
```

And after that you can use %env.dbuser% anywhere.